# Fill table with two datetime columns with random dates

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have table `T1` with two datetime columns (`StartDate`, `EndDate`) which I must populate with random dates under one circumstance:

- `EndDate` value must be greater than `StartDate` in minimal one day.

Example:

```
StartDate           EndDate
===========================
2001-04-04          2001-04-06  (2 days)
2001-01-05          2001-01-15  (10 days)
.
.
.
```

Can I do that in one statement?

P.S. My first idea was to change `EndDate` column to NULL, and in first step populate `StartDate` leaving `EndDate` as NULL, and in second statement to write some mechanism to update `EndDate` with dates greater (in different number of days for every record) then `StartDate`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that populates the table in one step:

```
insert into T1 (StartDate, EndDate)
select 
    X.StartDate,
    dateadd(day, abs(checksum(newid())) % 10, X.StartDate) EndDate
from  (
    select top 20
        dateadd(day, -abs(checksum(newid())) % 100, convert(date, getDate())) StartDate
    from sys.columns c1, sys.columns c2
) X
```

The query above uses some tricks that I personally often use in ad-hoc SQL queries:

- [`new_Id()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx) generates different random values for each row, as opposed to `RAND()`, which would be evaluated once per query. The expression `abs(checksum(newid())) % N` will generate random integer values in the `0 - N-1` range.
- the `TOP X ... FROM sys.columns c1, sys.columns c2` trick allows you to generate X rows whose values can be composed of scalar values, like the ones in our example.

Obviously, you can modify the hardcoded values in the above query to:

- generate more rows
- increase the range of random start dates
- increase the maximum duration of each row.

Answer (score 1):

Something simple using `rand()` function:

**[Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3a7f8/2)**

```
declare @records int = 100, --Number of records needed 
        @count int = 0, @start int, @end int

while(@records>@count)
begin
    select @start = rand() * 10, @end = rand() * 100, @count+=1
    insert into mytable
    select dateadd(day, @start, getdate()),dateadd(day, @end, getdate())
end

select * from mytable
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT T1 (StartDate, EndDate)
  select T1, T1 + add_days
  from 
  (select DATEADD(day, (ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 65530), 0) T1,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY number) add_days
   from [ master ] .. spt_values) X;
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ea183/1) example